# SQL search not working all of the time

Tags: php, mysql, sql, odbc

I am designing a front end with php to work with an access database backend using the ODBC connector.  The issue I am having is when I use a sql query to search the database, it only kind of works. The issue I am having is when I am searching the column of the FileNo, when I search through the description or the title, the search seems to work. When I search something like 111 it works, when I search 111.50, the results come up empty, but there are results with that value. but if I search something like 111.03, then the search works. And if I search for 111.00 once again the results comes up empty/ So from what I can tell, if I search for anything that ends in a zero it does not work.

- 111    <- works
- 111.00 <- Does not work
- 111.50 <- Does not work
- 111.5  <- works
- 111.03 <- works

In the code I use the LIKE command for the search on FileNo, that is the area that is having issues, I tried to use the equal to expression, but then I get an error on the syntax

Here is the code, for the php function/sql:

```
//Setting Search Results to a variable

$search = $_POST ['search'];
$search = trim ($search);



$search_sql = "
            SELECT * 
            FROM `Medical Literature`
            WHERE Title LIKE '%$search%'
             OR DrugName LIKE '%$search%'
             OR FileNo LIKE '%$search%'
                ";

$result = odbc_exec($connect, $search_sql);
```

And here is the code for the simple form to enable the search:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Med-Lite Search</title>
</head>

<body>
<body bgcolor="#B0B0B0 ">

<h2>Med-Lit Search<h2>
<form name= "MedLitSearch" method="post" action="MedLit_Search_Results.php">
<input name="search" type="text" size="100" maxlength= "100"/>
<input name="submit" type="submit" value="Search"/>

</form>

<hr>


</body>

</html>
```

Thanks in advance eveyone!! =)

Comment: I have a feeling it has something to do with the string "111.50" being converted into a number and thus cutting off the trailing 0 to make it 111.5 ... I'm just not sure where

Comment: Seems to be a single SQL mistake... Can you provide the structure of your table, or at least the type of `FileNo` column?

Comment: The FileNo field is a Number, Single Fixed Format, with 2 decimal places

Comment: It is converting FileNo to char in such a way that trailing zeros are lost.  Maybe if you explicitly convert FileNo yourself so trailing zeros are retained.  I don't use MySql so don't know proper syntax.

Comment: I tried something like this: $decimal_search = number_format($search, 2); and still did not work

Comment: If number_format is the right function then try putting it around FileNo like this: OR number_format(FileNo, 2) LIKE '%$search%'

Comment: I know the function works because I use a similar function somewhere else in my code, and it is about to bring back the zero at the end, just does not work when I use it for part of the sql search

Comment: So, my last suggestion did not work?

Comment: @user3525621 What is the syntax error you get when you try `OR FileNo = $search` ? That should work and also makes more sense when searching for a number..

Comment: @Galz Warning:odbc_exec(): SQL error: [Mircosoft] [ODBC Microsoft Access Driver] Too few parameters. Expected 1., SQL state 07001 in SQLExecDirect in (file and line number of code)

Comment: @user3525621 Did you try `OR FileNo = $search` or only `OR FileNo LIKE '%$search%'` as the example shows?

Comment: @Galz I tried both, when I use LIKE, it does not give me an error, but it does not work properly, when I use =, I get the error I mentioned above